# Redimensionar UITextView de acordo com a quantidade de conteúdo

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Estou criando um uma tela em que tem um `UITextView` que recebe o conteúdo de um Web Service, gostaria de saber como faço para que o `UITextView` se redimensione de acordo com a quantidade de conteúdo obtido, sem criar um Scroll no texto, apenas a View tem um `UIScrollView` que de acordo com o tamanho da `UITextView` ele determina o tamanho da abrangência do `UIScrollView` na tela, consegui fazer mas apenas quando altero o conteúdo, o problema é que não vou alterar, porque o conteúdo vem através de um feed. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
        CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
        CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
        CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
        newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
        textView.frame = newFrame;
    }
```

Comment: Checou minha resposta abaixo?

Answer (score 0):

Você está utilizando **Autolayout**?

Caso sim, desmarque a opção **Scrolling Enabled** no UITextView...

[image: Desabilitar Scrolling Enabled]

... remova constraint de altura (se houver) e defina as prioridades **Content Hugging** e **Content Compressions** para valores maiores do que as demais subviews da view principal.

[image: Aumentar prioridades do UITextView]

Tais mudanças devem resolver seu problema!